# ClickOnce deployment installing as a new application instead of update

Tags: c#, clickonce, code-signing-certificate

We have a C# application that is being deployed through a website, a new release is being tested, but something strange is going on with this release. Before release we test in a staging environment, which is a copy of the production.

Downloading the current version (cur_ver) from production and then downloading the release candidate (rc_ver) from staging results in the application being installed twice. The second install will be named "applicationname -1". Normally "cur_ver" would be overriden by "rc_ver", but not this time.

The only difference I can think of, is that I have updated the code signing certificate as this was running out. Can this really have this influence and how can I avoid this ?

Comment: I'm afraid that yes, updating the certificate has that effect, as it is seen as a different application. I know no way of solving this...

Comment: So just to make sure, signing the code with another certificate results in a "new" application seen from clickonce point of view ?

Comment: In my experience yes, that is the effect. Maybe someone here could provide us more info on this topic

Comment: Ok, thanks @Pikoh hopefully someone might be able to answer this. Just wondering if other things could result in same problem, like usage of newer versions of .net framework etc...

Comment: No..in my experience this happens only in case of a change of certificate, and of course if you change your namespace or assembly name.

Comment: I know to bring back is now welcome here in StackOverflow (which makes no sense, is better than open a duplicated topic).
I have this same problem, any new way to inform ClickOnce that it is the same application? Thank you.